# Unable to test for file located in C:\Users\Public\Desktop

Tags: batch-file, command, command-prompt

I am using Batch programming to test for a file in the C:\Users\Public\Desktop\ExampleFolder1 on my computer. I don't have admin rights to my computer so I'm not sure if that would matter. But the computer is not recognizing that the file exists in the C:\Users\Public\Desktop\ExampleFolder1 folder. Can anyone help me with this? I'll past my code below.

```
if not exist %public%\Desktop\ExampleFolder1\ATLIS.lnk mkdir %userprofile%\Desktop\QLSShortcuts (

%systemroot%\System32\xcopy /y %userprofile%\Libraries\Documents %userprofile%\Desktop\ExampleFolder1 /E

echo *************** QLS SHORTCUTS FOLDED HAS BEEN CREATED ON YOUR DESKTOP **************
echo *************** YOU CAN USE THE NELLAB / FLALAB / OR DALLAB SHORTCUTS **************
echo *************** LET MARK KNOW IF YOU NEED ANY OTHERS **************

) else if exist %public%\Desktop\ExampleFolder1 (

echo EXIST

)
```

This code always copies a new directory to the desktop. Regardless if I run it two or three times. So it is not checking to see if the file already exist because it is as if it can't look in the %public%\ExampleFolder1\ATLIS.lnk directory which is really frustrating. I even did the below trick that I learned on stackoverflow where you test for the path of what it's doing.

```
echo %public%\Desktop\ExampleFolder1\ATLIS.lnk
```

returns "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\ExampleFolder1\ATLIS.lnk" in the command prompt. But this shouldn't be happening because the computer should be able to see that %public%\Desktop\ExampleFolder1\ATLIS.lnk exists and then skip the section of the code where it copies the files. So what am I doing wrong here? Why can't I check for that file so that the code will execute properly. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Best practice is to always put quotes around your file and folder paths.

Comment: What should happen here: `if not exist %public%\Desktop\ExampleFolder1\ATLIS.lnk mkdir %userprofile%\Desktop\QLSShortcuts (`? should the `mkdir` command also be executed conditionally? if so, move it into the parenthesised section (or put an `&` before the `(`)...

Comment: No I want the mkdir command to NOT be executed if that file exisits. If C:\Users\Public\Desktop\ExampleFolder1\ATLIS.lnk exists than it should not execute the code. But it IS executing the code, every time. Quotes are not needed because there are no spaces in the file path.

Comment: I'm really starting to think that this is happening because I don't have access to modify the %public%\Desktop\ExampleFolder1 directory. But do you need Admin rights to check if the %public%\Desktop\ExampleFolder1\ATLIS.lnk file exists?

Comment: Read the help for the IF command. Your syntax is wrong. Regardless of not having spaces, it never ever hurts to use the quotes. Just make it apart of your normal coding practice.

Comment: Do you want to check the `.lnk` file for existence or the link target? the latter is not possible with pure batch scripting...